# Diophantine Approximation on Quadratic Polynomials

Tags: number-theory, approximation, diophantine-approximation

Given an integer $a$ which is not a perfect square, I'd like to ask how to perform Diophantine Approximation of $\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ to $a$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers. Specifically, integers satisfying $|\frac{x^2}{y^2}-a|<\epsilon$ are preferred.

Comment: Set $y$ to a power of $10$.

Comment: Just find a rational approximation $\frac{x}{y}$ (for example with the continued fraction method) of $\sqrt{a}$. This gives a reasonable approximation of the desired form.